# Can't login to Math.SE. Too many redirects

Tags: support, login

I am trying to login to Math.SE from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/login using my Google OpenID (by clicking the Google button). It can't open the page due to too many redirects (I am already logged in to Google). Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: I'm very sorry for not drawing freehand.]

I don't know if the fault is on Stack Exchange's or Google's end, but I want to use Math.SE. I don't yet have an account on Math.SE.

What could be the problem?

---

The same happens for other sites where I don't have an account, like Android and Stats.

Comment: Could this be a Safari-only problem? Try another browser.

Comment: I've gotten this when I've had cookie accept disabled (anyone know why MobileSafari in iOS 5 keeps turning cookie accepts off? Grrr...) Re-enabling cookies fixed this for me.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta clearing cookies fixed the problem. :) Can you post an answer?

Comment: Your ellipse looks suspiciously not-freehand...

Comment: @AakashM see the alt text of the image.

Comment: @WTP: done.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem (in Mobile Safari) when cookie accept is disabled, during the OpenID reauthentication process. Check that you're accepting cookies. And you might as well clear cookies while you're there.